# Subscribers with Date 90 days older than current date

Tags: shell, awk, sed, solaris

I have to display only those subscribers which are in "unconnected state" and the date is 90 days older than today's date.

Below command is used for this purpose:

```
cat vfsubscriber_20170817.csv | sed -e 's/^"//' -e '1d' | nawk -F '",' '{if ( (substr($11,2,4) == 2017) &&  ( substr($11,2,8) -lt $dm )&&($9=="\"unconnected") ) print $1,substr($11,2,8),$dm}' dm=$(perl -e 'use
POSIX qw(strftime); print strftime "%Y%m%d",localtime(time()- 3600*24*90);') >  ${EXTRACT_FILE}
```

Problem is that this expression is not getting evaluated : `( substr($11,2,8) -lt $dm )`

```
dm=$(perl -e 'use
POSIX qw(strftime); print strftime "%Y%m%d",localtime(time()- 3600*24*90);')
```

results into "20170520" which is correct.

Please help me to get this expression evaluated and compared correctly in the command.

Comment: The multi-post: https://askubuntu.com/q/947419

Comment: by the way, title is misleading, you'd rather "how to use an external computed value  within awk"

Answer (score 1):

`dm=$( )` is evaluated outside awk, try

```
... | nawk -v dm=$(perl ... ) ' ... '
```

And do not use `-lt` but `<` in awk.

Comment: Yes dm=$() is getting calculated outside awk.
Can you please help with the updated command?

Comment: The updated command should look like ?

cat vfsubscriber_20170817.csv | sed -e 's/^"//' -e '1d' | nawk -v dm=$(perl -e 'use POSIX qw(strftime); print strftime "%Y%m%d",localtime(time()- 3600*24*90);') -F '",' '{if ( (sub
str($11,2,4) == 2017) && ( substr($11,2,8) -lt $dm ) && ($9=="\"unconnected") ) print $1,substr($11,2,8),$dm}'  >  ${EXTRACT_FILE}

I tried with the above way, it doesn't help :(